# using np.exp() to convert column in pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
id  val
1   10
1   2012
1   65
```

i want to convert the val column to create values that add up to 1

```
df['val'] = np.exp(df.val)/sum(np.exp(df.val))
```

but i get the following

```
id  val
1   0.0
1   NaN
1   0.0
```

how can i take care of this to make probabilities equal to 1 for this case?

Comment: check `np.exp(2012)` result, that's the reason

Comment: i know it is exploding but if it's just a large number should i just make the value 1?

Comment: that depends of what you expect from result. What did you mean with "that add up to 1" ?

Comment: This is the softmax function. I'd use some ml package. See the dup question for non-overflow implementation; basically, substract the `val` by its max before applying your function.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question correctly.
You can divide each value in the `val` column by `sum` of all the values in the `val` column:

```
df['val']/df['val'].sum()

0    0.004792
1    0.964063
2    0.031145
Name: val, dtype: float64
```